# How can I make actual image files persistent in file upload process running with docker?

Tags: php, docker, file-upload

Recently I have developed an application running with docker in PHP including file upload process.

However, actual uploaded files to the server would have been lost when the container exits.

How did you deal with the matter?
Please tell me how to make files persistent.

For example:

- Using external server like S3 for storing files.
- Utilizing Docker storage functions for volumes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using docker compose. You will be able to access the files inside container by mounting them to external host directory. The files uploaded to wordpress are stored in `wp-content/uploads` and you can mount this using this sample docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-database:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql-database
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  wordpress-sites:
    image: wordpress:custom
    build:
      context: ./wordpress
      dockerfile: wordpress.dockerfile
    container_name: wordpress-sites
    links:
      - mysql-database
    depends_on:
      - mysql-database
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

The documentation regarding [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) should be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I want to learn various ideas of many people and make them lead to my development but is using docker compose the most popular way of making files persistent? 
Is there the another way ?

Comment: Volume is more oftenly used for persistence but I have not used them in Dockerfile, I just have used in docker-compose, therefore, the answer. You can use volumes in Dockerfile also in a similar way for persistence of data

Comment: Volumes are not specific to docker-compose. There is nothing wrong with using docker-compose, but it certainly is not some sort of requirement to be using that in order to achieve persistence by using volumes. You can use volumes using the `docker` CLI directly as well.